# jQuery global variabiles $.post();

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, post, var

```
$.post("general.php", {/* some values */}, function(data){var id = data;});
alert(id);
```

The problem is that, alert is empty. Do know anyone why? And how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 problems :

- one is that the ajax is asynchronous and the alert executes before the ajax callback, where the `id` variable is being set
- the second one is that the variable is not global, it is only visible in the callback scope

So, I suggest you declare the variable global (if you need it for later use) :

```
var id;// in the global scope
```

or

```
window.id = '';
```

And you should probably execute the logic in the callback :

```
$.post("general.php", {/* some values */}, function(data){ 
    window.id = data;
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But there is one other problem. If you run this code the first time, it does not work. The second time it works. That is the first problem. How to fix it?

Comment: it should work the first time too.could you make a fiddle out of your code ?

Comment: I can not make a fiddle, because there is need another file to be loaded. I think it should be work ok first time too, but there i got maybe other simple mistake.